# Как считать из файла в переменную число 10*Е100

Tags: c++

Опыта написания программ у меня еще маловато. Столкнулся с задачей считать три числа из файла и сравнить их. На небольших числах все работает но при значениях (по условиям задачи)  10*Е100 никаких цифровых форматов не хватает.

Comment: Значит, придется сравнивать посимвольно...

Comment: Можете полное условие задачи привести? Не исключено, что в данной задаче можно оперирвать с числами, представленными в виде строк.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Число приведено в экспоненциальной форме? Если в обычной, то простой алгоритм сравнения в строковом виде (и что тут некрасиво?).

```
int big_compare(char *n1, char *n2) {
    int l1 = strlen(n1);
    int l2 = strlen(n2);

    if ( l1 == l2 ) {
        int i;
        for( i = 0; n1[i]; i++ ) {
            if ( n1[i] != n2[i] ) 
                return ((int) n1[i] - (int) n2[i]);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    else
        return (l1 - l2);
}
```

Comment: Тогда уж if (l1 == l2) return strcmp(n1, n2);

Comment: я думаю, реализация strcmp от этого кода не сильно отличается. кстати и все реализации библиотек длинной арифметики тоже. там просто сравниваются не символы а элементы массивов

Comment: не совсем понял конструкцию: char *n1, char *n2.. 
strlen/strcmp - это модуль string.h или sstream.h?

Comment: Это на сермяжном C - указатели на массив символов (строку). Объявлены в string.h

Comment: Блин... Ответ то я принял, так как уже понял что сравнивать нужно именно строки, но никак не могу понять как считать строку если заранее неизвестна ее длинна? числа читаю так: freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
scanf("%ld",&a); // здесь -> a int ))
А как считать строку, да еще только до пробела?

Comment: Ну, сколько там максимально цифр будет? Читайте в строку. Задайте буфер этак в тысячу символов. В файле перевод строки

   char n1[1024];
   fgets(n1, sizeof(n1), stdin);

Comment: Так. В общем все работает, кроме случая, когда первое или второе число равно 0. Почему - не могу понять. Вот код реализации:

    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cin >> c;

    if ((big_compare (a, b) == 1) && (big_compare (a, c) == 1))
        cout << a;

    else if (big_compare (b, c) == 1)
        cout << b;

    else
        cout << c;

    // a,b и с массивы char[100].

И еще - по условиям задачи число не больше 100 символов.

Comment: Не единица. сравнение возвращает отрицательное число, если первый параметр меньше второго, положительное, если второй параметр меньше и 0 в случае равенства.
Предел комментирования достигнут, поэтом уотвечаю здесь. 
Вы переделали неправильно. сравнение  строк n1 и n2 в лоб не сработает

Comment: я ее переделал:
int big_compare(char *n1, char *n2)
{

 int l1 = strlen(n1);
 int l2 = strlen(n2);
 if (l1 > l2) return 1;
 else if (l1 == l2) if (n1 > n2) return 1;
 else return 2;
}

Comment: @Sorojama: тест провалится на числах 00001 и 002.

Answer (score 8):

Берем любую подходящую библиотеку для больших чисел и вперед

- [C++ Big Integer Library](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/)
- [C++ BigInt class by alexvn](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-bigint/)
- [How to implement big int in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269268/how-to-implement-big-int-in-c)

Но учитывая, что это олимпиада, рекомендую посмотреть эти библиотеки и научится делать хотя бы сложение вычитание самостоятельно, храня число в виде строки (для начала, а потом искать более красивые и оптимальные пути).

Comment: Был у нас в корпорации конкурс молодых программистов. было несколько заданий такого примерно типа: У вас есть функция, которая ставит точку в любом месте монитора (по двум координатам). Используя только эту функцию, построить любой трехмерный график. Решить принципиально на бумаге. Лишившись гугля и располагая только собственными мозгами, юные хакеры не смогли придумать ни одной путной идеи. Вообще ни одной

Comment: потому что они скорее всего были программистами с фреймворками (то есть java, C# и подобные языки). Думаю, они и сортировку пузырьком не написали бы.

Comment: у нас большая корпорация и там было много очень разных программистов. Их проблема не во фреймворке, а в отсутствии фундаментального образования. Они умеют программировать, но не умеют решать задачи (в общем смысле того слова)

Answer (score 4):

Господа, здесь же не требуется выполнять никаких операций с числами! нужно всего лишь их сравнить. А это почти то же самое, что сравнить строки. Т.е. нужно просто зачитать строки и сравить их поразрядно, начиная со старших. Т.е. если длина (количество цифр) одного числа меньше другого - то и само число меньше. Если длины совпадают - то нужно просто сравнивать цифры начиная со старших разрядов.

Comment: вполне может быть. но задачи бывают разные:) Может там сумму первых двух с третьим сравнить:) посмотрим, что ТС напишет.

Comment: я ответил на заданный вопрос :-) в нем ничего про сумму не сказано

Comment: Никаких сумм, только сравнение (нужно указать наибольшее).

Answer (score 0):

Создать свой класс для больших чисел и в нем переопределить арифметические операции.

Comment: Можно и свой класс но думаю задача должна решаться проще.

Answer (score 0):

Для работы с большими экспонентами пойдет тип long double, хотя его реализация зависит от платформы. А для работы с целыми произвольной разрядности можно взять библиотеку [C++ Big Integer Library](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/).

Comment: это олимпиадное задание